# Circle object changes position depending on image save format in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have to place a circle in a specific spot in an image. The problem is that the image is plotted in an semi-log scale, which distorts the circle unless I use some specific transform. However, when I do that, the circle changes position depending if I save the image as A PDF or PNG. Here's a MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Circle
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.text import OffsetFrom


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(11,5), squeeze=False,
    gridspec_kw = {'width_ratios':[3, 1]}, subplot_kw=dict(aspect="auto"))

x=np.logspace(-2,1)
y=np.linspace(.5,0,x.size)

ax=axes[0,0]
ax.semilogx(x, y)
circ = Circle((.5, .5), .1, transform="none", facecolor="none", edgecolor="k")
ax.add_patch(circ)

ax.set(xlim=(1e-2, 1e1), ylim=(0, .6))
fig.savefig("circle.png")
```

And here are the two outputs depending on how I save the image:

[image]
[image]

I have also tried using `transform=ax.transAxes` and, while it preserves the location of the circle, it's not a circle anymore after the semilog transformation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a [known issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9220). The problem is that pdf is always saved with a dpi of 72, while png will take the figure dpi into account.

However, instead of creating a circle directly in the figure or axes, I would recommend playing around with the [Annotation BBox tools](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/demo_annotation_box.html).

You may create an AnnotationBBox with a DrawingArea inside. The DrawingArea may contain the circle. The coordinates of the DrawingArea are points. 
The AnnotationBbox can be placed anywhere on the axes or figure and its position may be specified in some other coordinate system like axes coordinates or data coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Circle
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.offsetbox import DrawingArea, AnnotationBbox


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(11,5), squeeze=False,
    gridspec_kw = {'width_ratios':[3, 1]}, subplot_kw=dict(aspect="auto"))

x=np.logspace(-2,1)
y=np.linspace(.5,0,x.size)

ax=axes[0,0]
ax.semilogx(x, y)

##################
# Axes Coordinates
# Create circle of 10 points radius
da = DrawingArea(1,1, 0, 0)
p = Circle((0, 0), 10)
da.add_artist(p)

# Place box in the middle ((.5,.5)) of the axes.
# Add circle inside drawing area to box
ab = AnnotationBbox(da, (.5,.5), xycoords='axes fraction',
                    box_alignment=(0, 0), frameon=False, pad=0.0)
ax.add_artist(ab)

###################
# Data Coordinates
# Create circle of 10 points radius
da = DrawingArea(1,1, 0, 0)
p = Circle((0, 0), 10, color="crimson")
da.add_artist(p)

# Place box at (0.1,0.3) in data coordinates.
# Add circle inside drawing area to box
ab = AnnotationBbox(da, (0.1,0.3), xycoords='data',
                    box_alignment=(0, 0), frameon=False, pad=0.0)
ax.add_artist(ab)




ax.set(xlim=(1e-2, 1e1), ylim=(0, .6))
fig.savefig("circle.png")
fig.savefig("circle.pdf")
plt.show()
```

The resulting pdf and png will now be identical

[image]